# Table view won't push to next view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode5

I have this code for a drop down textfield so that when the user click a row in the table view it pushes to the next view but for some reason this doesn't happen. Is there something wrong with my code. Because the app doesn't crash I have no error warning and no idea why it doesn't work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {

[delegate dropDownCellSelected:indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:cellText forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

ShiftCalculatorViewController *shiftCalculatorViewController =    
[[ShiftCalculatorViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:shiftCalculatorViewController animated:YES  
completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You're doing a couple of things wrong. You shouldn't get data from a cell -- cells are for displaying data, not for supplying it. You should set the value of cellText from the array you use to populate the table. Second, you shouldn't use alloc init to get an instance of ShiftCalculatorViewController unless you've made its view in code (no xib or storyboard). You should use either initWithNibName:bundle: (if you made it in a xib), or instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: (if made in a storyboard).

Comment: what exactly does `dropDownCellSelected` do?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that you haven't set the delegate of your `UITableView` instance and therefore any delegate methods such as the -didSelectRowAtIndexPath won't be called.

```
[self.tableView setDelegate:self]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have written navigation controller code in app delegate and tableview delegate is setted in your current view controller and then write this

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  // in tableview you will be passing information from an array/dictionary in cell configure method so use the same array/dictionary to get information also.

 [delegate dropDownCellSelected:indexPath.row];
 NSString *cellText = yourArray[indexPath.row];

 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:cellText forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

 ShiftCalculatorViewController *shiftCalculatorViewController =    
 [[ShiftCalculatorViewController alloc] init];
 [self presentViewController:shiftCalculatorViewController animated:YES  
 completion:nil];
 }
 /// if still app crashes enable exception break point in left menu of your Xcode this will help you to know at which line of code app crashed.
```